# Typescript warnings when using interface and OpaqueToken in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been following the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#non-class-dependencies) and use **ng-cli**.

I created the following configuration file (**app-config.ts**):

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface AppConfig {
  supportTelephoneNumber: string;
}

export let APP_CONFIG_t = new OpaqueToken('app.config');

export const APP_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  supportTelephoneNumber: '1111 111 1111'
};
```

and in my **app.module.ts** file I have:

```
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UkCurrencyPipe,
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true }),
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: APP_CONFIG_t, useValue: APP_CONFIG },
    ...
```

I use this configuration in my **app.component.ts** file like this:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_CONFIG_t, AppConfig } from './app-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG_t) public config: AppConfig) {

  callSupport(): void {
    window.location.href = 'tel:+' + this.config.supportTelephoneNumber;
  }
}
```

When I serve my app using **ng serve** everything seems to work fine but I do see these warnings in the console from where I run **ng server**:

> WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts
> 40:166 export 'AppConfig' was not found in './app-config'
>
> WARNING in ./src/app/app.component.ts
> 40:195 export 'AppConfig' was not found in './app-config'

Does anyone know what these warnings mean and whether or not I should worry about them?

**My Versions**

- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.6
- ng-cli: v1.0.0-beta.16
- angular: v2.0.1
- typescript: v2.0.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As per [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034#issuecomment-249813801) on issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034

> having the same issue. (Works fine despite warning)
>   are you exporting more than one interface/class/const from the file?
>   issue stopped for me after i exported each interface from its own dedicated file.
>
> meaning if i had one file with multiple exports - i got warnings in build (export 'MyInterface1' was not found in '../file')
>
> `file.ts`

```
export interface MyInterface1 {}
export interface MyInterface2 {}
```

> after refactor - no warning
>
> `file1.ts`

```
export interface MyInterface1 {}
```

> `file2.ts`

```
export interface MyInterface2 {}
```