# Untrue 'not found' warnings in Angular-CLI/Webpack project

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, angular-cli

I'm getting a bunch of warnings like the following that things cannot be found but they are in the right places and my app runs so the warnings must be wrong. I'm using webpack version 2.1.0-beta.22 and webpack-dev-server              2.1.0-beta.10. My project is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-angular2-example/blob/master/src/app/core/store/claim/claim.model.ts#L3)

Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks!

```
[WDS] Warnings while compiling.
client:73 ./src/app/debate/claim/claim.component.ts
38:55 export 'Claim' was not found in '../../core/store/claim/claim.model'
Error: export 'Claim' was not found in '../../core/store/claim/claim.model'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getWarnings (/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:34:14)
    at /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:645:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:644:22
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyWarnings (/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:643:9)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/Dan/work/bernierebuttals/gba/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:505:8)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compilation.finish
```

[Full stack trace](https://gist.github.com/dancancro/f3eeb5fec85958eeb18887950b61cab8)

The file structure looks like this:

```
app
├── core

│   ├── store

│   │   ├── claim
│   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   ├── claim.actions.ts
│   │   │   ├── claim.effects.ts
│   │   │   ├── claim.model.ts
│   │   │   └── claim.reducer.ts

├── debate
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── claim
│   │   ├── claim.component.css
│   │   ├── claim.component.html
│   │   ├── claim.component.spec.ts
│   │   └── claim.component.ts
```

and from `./src/app/core/store/claim/claim.model.ts`

```
import { Rebuttal } from '../rebuttal/rebuttal.model';

export interface Claim {
...
```

Comment: You should probably start by cleaning up your project. There are two `tsconfig.json` files: one in the root directory and one in the `src` directory. It's difficult to know which one you expect to be used. Then your `package.json` defines several times the same dependencies. Try to properly separate the dev dependencies (such as `style-loader`, `css-loader`...) from the runtime dependencies.

Comment: @osechet Thank you. As you could probably tell, I've mashed together partial, simplified examples into one project in a hopeful attempt to synthesize what employed developers work on in real life. Naturally each example does things its own way without much explanation why. One of them had all the front-end deps in devDependencies. `tsconfig.json` appeared in different places. And so on. I merged the two `tsconfig.json`s into one and am getting new errors but will keep working on it. I didn't want you to think I ignored your help, which I appreciate.

Comment: That did it! I made one more tweak to `tsconfig.json` and the warnings are gone.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe these links can solve your problem: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890963/2130322) and [[2]](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034)

So I tried to add a new file to export only in the interface, and the warnings are gone:

I created the interfaces file for claim, claim-rebuttal and rebuttal:

```
/** /src/app/core/store/claim/claim.interface.ts */
export { Claim } from './claim.model'


/** /src/app/core/store/claim-rebuttal/claim-rebuttal.interface.ts */
export { ClaimRebuttal } from './claim-rebuttal.model'


/** /src/app/core/store/rebuttal/rebuttal.interface.ts */
export { Rebuttal } from './rebuttal.model'
```

Then I exported this in the index.ts

```
export { Claim } from './claim/claim.interface'
export { Rebuttal } from './rebuttal/rebuttal.interface'
export { ClaimRebuttal } from './claim-rebuttal/claim-rebuttal.interface'
```

Finally, it just to change it in the claim.component and others files:

```
import { Claim, Rebuttal, ClaimRebuttal }  from '../../core/store';
// ...

@Component({ ...})
export class ClaimComponent {
```

and also in rebuttal component:

```
import { Rebuttal, Claim }  from '../../core/store';

@Component({...})
export class RebuttalComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I guess I lucked out and fixed the problem with @ocechet's advice by removing an extra `tsconfig.json` file instead of the solution you proposed. I'll remember this for next time. Hopefully the bug is gone before I encounter it.